# How to define a link path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, path, associations, link-to

I'm trying to figure out how to make an app with Rails 4. I keep getting stuck on basic things and I don't seem to be able to identify principles to use going forward.

I have a profile model and a industry model. The associations are:

Profile:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :industries, join_table: 'industries_profiles'
```

Industry:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :profiles, join_table: 'industries_profiles'
```

In my profile show page, I'm now trying to link to the industry page:

```
<% @profile.industries.limit(5).each do |industry| %>

    <%= link_to industry.sector.upcase, industry_path(@industry) %> 

<% end %>
```

I can't find anything that works for this link.

I have tried the following:

```
industry_path(@profile.industry)
industry_path(@profile.industry_id)
industry_path(industry)
industry_path(profile.industry)
industry_path(industry.id)
industry_path(industry_id)
```

But all of them are guesses. I don't know how to ready the API dock so I can't understand any of its content.

Can anyone see how to link to a show page of the other side of the HABTM association for a single record?

Comment: What do you have your routes.rb file? `industry_path(industry)` is one you should be using.

Comment: I have: resources :industries

Comment: When I try that, when I hover over the link, it shows a path which has the right industry id in it. But I can't click on it - nothing happens

Comment: As Ben said, `industry_path(industry)` should work, what do you mean by 'nothing happens'? if the href has the id on it, then it's working OK

Comment: Try this way: <%= link_to industry.sector.upcase, @industry %>

Comment: There's not enough information to effectively answer this question. Can you post the section of your `routes.rb` that includes the routes for both the `profile` and `industry` resources?

Comment: Did you write a migration for the join table?

Comment: I did.  Ben/Jan are right in the format of the link. I don't know what was causing the problem. I was trying to get it working in safari - I don't know whether there is an explanation but when I tried in chrome/firefox it worked. Then when I went back to safari, it also worked. I'm not sure whether there is a reason to explain this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can grab a list of your routes by running `rake routes | grep industry` in your command line, which will give you a table with the prefix, action, and uri pattern. For example:

```
   industries GET    /industries(.:format)           industries#index
              POST   /industries(.:format)           industries#create
 new_industry GET    /industries/new(.:format)       industries#new
edit_industry GET    /industries/:id/edit(.:format)  industries#edit
     industry GET    /industries/:id(.:format)       industries#show
              PATCH  /industries/:id(.:format)       industries#update
              PUT    /industries/:id(.:format)       industries#update
              DELETE /industries/:id(.:format)       industries#destroy
```

In your case, you should look at the `show` path. Which is industry and you append `_path` to the end of whatever your prefix is above, which comes out to be `industry_path`. And since you have declared your variable `industry` when defining your loop, you can use that instead of the instance variable.

Short answer: `industry_path(industry)`